# Pagination in Getting the File

Tags: java, java-8, pagination, java-stream

I have a location where 3000 files is stored. But i want to get the list of 1000 files at a time and in next call another 1000 files and so on.

Please find my below code :

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
public class FileSystem {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        FileSystem.createListFile();
        FileSystem.getFileInBatch();
    }
    private static void getFileInBatch() {
        int MAX_INDEX= 1000;
            try (Stream<Path> walk = Files.walk(Paths.get("C://FileTest"))) {
                List<String> result = walk.filter(p -> Files.isRegularFile(p) && p.getFileName().toString().endsWith(".txt"))
                        .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(FileSystem::pathToInt))
                        .map(x -> x.toString()).limit(MAX_INDEX).collect(Collectors.toList());
                result.forEach(System.out::println);
                System.out.println(result.size());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
    private static int pathToInt(final Path path) {
        return Integer.parseInt(path.getFileName()
                .toString()
                .replaceAll("Aamir(\\d+).txt", "$1")
        );
    }
    private static void createListFile() throws IOException {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3000; i++) {
            File file = new File("C://FileTest/Aamir" + i + ".txt");
            if (file.createNewFile()) {
                System.out.println(file.getName() + " is created!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am able to get the first 1000 (Aamir0.txt to Aamir999.txt) files using the limit in streams.

Now how can i get the next 1000 files ( Aamir1000.txt to Aamir1999.txt)

Answer (score 0):

You can use skip in your Stream. For example:

```
int toSkip = 1000; // define as method param/etc.

List<String> result = walk.filter(p -> Files.isRegularFile(p) && p.getFileName().toString().endsWith(".txt"))
  .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(FileSystem::pathToInt))
  .map(x -> x.toString()).skip(toSkip).limit(MAX_INDEX).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: But then how it works for the first case. I want to get 1000 files every time until I didn't get all the files in the directory.

Comment: I think we should have a loop so I will get first 1000 files. Then another 1000 files until i get the whole files in directory.

Comment: If you need all the files - just read all the files and don't use skip/limit at all. If you want to read 1000 files once, then you have to store how many files you already processed and skip them in the next call.

Comment: How to use loops to get the files and when I will get to know I have got the all the files.